# export php query result to ascii txt file

Tags: php, ascii, text-files

I'm a noobie in PHP and I have a problem: how can I export a php-mysql query result into a ascii txt file with pre-definied spaces?
I searched into the web and in my books but I didn't find a specific solution. Could anyone help me, please? Thanks in advance

Comment: What you actually want to achieve? The question doesn’t tell the result you want to be shown in the file.

Comment: Hi, I have a page with the result of a query in different tables of the database. The page shows the data in a classical html table format. Now I have to put the data into a txt ASCII file (after this file will be sent in email) with pre-defiened spaces. I hope I was more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need these functions to convert query result to text:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

For file writing:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php

Comment: Thank you Im0rtality, I'll try to follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You better read documents on how text files are bit-written. There are many charset used to memorized documents on your drive. It depends the charset that you've defined saving the data on your database and if your php function is changing the charset when it fetches the same data.

here's an example of charset manipulation (converts iso-8859-1 to utf-8) : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

you might want read your file bit-wised and converts all the chars that are in the range of the ascii table and sweep off the others, but unless your document is in an other type than ascii to the first origin, you probably let the file in its predefined charset.